# Ruby on Rails - Bundler MySQL Error: Failed to build gem native extension

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was trying to create a new Rails project. When I ran `bundle install`, I got an error for some reason. Can anyone tell me why this error is occurred and how to fix it?

I ran: `bundle install`
Result:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)Using atomic (1.1.14)
 
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)Using rack (1.5.2)
 
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using bundler (1.5.0.rc.1)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using thor (0.18.1)Using hike (1.2.3)
 
Using json (1.8.1)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sass (3.2.13)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using uglifier (2.4.0)Using sprockets (2.10.1)
 
Using activesupport (4.0.2)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using actionpack (4.0.2)
Using jbuilder (1.5.3)
Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
Using activemodel (4.0.2)
Using railties (4.0.2)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using activerecord (4.0.2)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using turbolinks (2.1.0)
Using rails (4.0.2)
 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
    /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
 
Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
 
 
Gem files will remain installed in /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
 
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.14), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.14'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I ran: `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.14'`
Result:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql2:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
    /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
 
Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
 
 
Gem files will remain installed in /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
```

I ran: `bundle install`
Result:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Using rake (10.1.1)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using minitest (4.7.5)
Using multi_json (1.8.2)
Using atomic (1.1.14)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using builder (3.1.4)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.3)
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3)
Using arel (4.0.1)
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using bundler (1.5.0.rc.1)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using thor (0.18.1)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using tilt (1.4.1)
Using sass (3.2.13)
Using thread_safe (0.1.3)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using uglifier (2.4.0)
Using activesupport (4.0.2)
Using rack (1.5.2)
Using mail (2.5.4)
Using sdoc (0.3.20)
Using activemodel (4.0.2)Using jbuilder (1.5.3)
 
Using rack-test (0.6.2)Using sprockets (2.10.1)
 
Using activerecord (4.0.2)
Using actionpack (4.0.2)
Using actionmailer (4.0.2)
Using railties (4.0.2)
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.1)
Using coffee-rails (4.0.1)
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4)
Using rails (4.0.2)
Using sass-rails (4.0.1)
Using turbolinks (2.1.0)
 
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
 
    /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_without_gvl() in ruby/thread.h... yes
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for rb_wait_for_single_fd()... yes
checking for rb_hash_dup()... yes
checking for rb_intern3()... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lm... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lz... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lsocket... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lnsl... yes
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
checking for main() in -lmygcc... no
checking for mysql_query() in -lmysqlclient... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
 
Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysql-config
    --without-mysql-config
    --with-mysql-dir
    --without-mysql-dir
    --with-mysql-include
    --without-mysql-include=${mysql-dir}/include
    --with-mysql-lib
    --without-mysql-lib=${mysql-dir}/
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mlib
    --without-mlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-zlib
    --without-zlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-socketlib
    --without-socketlib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-nsllib
    --without-nsllib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
    --with-mygcclib
    --without-mygcclib
    --with-mysqlclientlib
    --without-mysqlclientlib
 
 
Gem files will remain installed in /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/olcay/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/ext/mysql2/gem_make.out
 
An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.14), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.14'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

Don't mark as duplicate, just send the link of the question and tell me to delete this post.
My operating system is Ubuntu.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: @Cdub Ubuntu. This comment length limit is so frustrating!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you don't have the `libmysqlclient-dev` package installed:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
gem install mysql2
```

Then try:

```
bundle install
```